# GCP Bigtable : Availability within a zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, distributed-system, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

**Background**

I am planning to use GCP's Bigtable (BT) offering for one of my projects.
This is a *NOT_SO_CRITICAL* use-case, hence i am exploring a single cluster setup (COST factor).

**Question**

What are the intra-zone High Availability (HA) gurantees for Bigtable ?

I am ok for any outages which occur at the zone level (relatively rare event, acceptable for my use-case). Concern for me is BT causing outages incase of single machine going down as part of ad-hoc maintenance.

PS : Google only allows a single big-table cluster (per BT instance) within an availability zone. This makes me believe even more that there would be some HA guarantees within a zone, but not getting any documentation around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the intra-zone High Availability (HA) gurantees for Bigtable
> ?

The Covered Service will provide a Monthly Uptime Percentage to Customer as follows (the "Service Level Objective" or "SLO"):

> Cloud Bigtable - Zonal instance (single cluster) >= 99.9%

[Cloud Bigtable Service Level Agreement (SLA)](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/sla)